# Hibernate one-to-many redundant update statements

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

TableA is the parent of TableB and they have a one-to-many relationship. The FK in TableB is TableA_Id.

Corresponding entity classes are A and B.
In the entity class A I have the following code:

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name=”TableA_Id”,nullable=false)
List<B> bs = new ArrayList<>();
```

In my main method I create an instance of A and two instances of B which I then add to the ArrayList in the A and then I execute `session.save` A.

In the generated queries, I see three insert statements and two update statements- the update statements seem redundant. When I look at the host variables (parameters) in the log, the same values for TableA_Id that were specified in the 2 inserts for the Inserts of the TableB, are repeated in the Update statements.

Any thoughts on why this behavior exists?

Comment: maybe this post will be helpful: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: Thanks Rann! It was helpful.